# HTML how to disable select in text input field

Tags: jquery, html, select, input

I have a text `input` with a jQuery `datepicker` to choose dates, and I don't want it to be a possibility to select the text inside of it if someone were to double click the box or so, how can I disable this?

```
unselectable="on"
```

&

```
user-select: none;
```

did not work for me, is there another way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this solution should work for you:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly">
```

Answer (score 0):

use a `span/div` as a parent of the input control and on click of this element-show the datepicker

use disabled property on the input control:

```
<input type="text" disabled>
```

Comment: well, that disables the function of the datepicker as well :/